# Why don't we consider the voltage drop due to inductance of conductors in dc motors?

Tags: dc-motor

In a dc motor, V = Eb + Ia.Ra

why don't we add the effect of inductance of coils.

Comment: Inductors are a short circuit in DC analysis. Inductors play a role in transient and AC analysis, and they form part of the "reactance" or complex impedance of the system..

Comment: Can you elaborate on the meaning of the different variables in your formula? Context is important here. Where did you find the formula?

Answer (score 5):

We do. The mathematical model of a DC motor includes both armature resistance and armature inductance. These two terms give rise to an 'electrical time constant', which is small compared to the 'mechanical time constant', so the electrical one is often ignored. Electrical time constant is \$\tau_e = L_a/R_a\$, and the Mechanical time constant is \$\tau_m = J/b\$ where J is the motor inertia and b is the viscous damping constant.

The reason that armature resistance, alone, is not ignored is that it has a significant effect on the steady state speed. Armature inductance only affects the transient response, and that only slightly, as the mechanical components are dominant.

Answer (score 1):

Because we are concerned with the steady state behavior. For DC voltages & currents in the steady state, inductances act as short circuits and therefore, they don't add into the KVL equation you wrote.

Comment: But the rotor coils are commutated, so they are carrying AC, yes?

Comment: Yes, but the polarities are setup in such a way that the voltage will not alternate between Vrate + and Vrate -. The commentator is setup to flip over...so it always stays positive.

Comment: In response to Chu's comment below. Yes he is right. However, given the question you asked is quite basic, I would assume you are an undergraduate which means you would probably have no use for the detailed models he is referring.